# Can we get a graph not containing $K_n$ with $\chi(G)\geq n$

Tags: graph-theory

It is known that the chromatic number of a complete graph is equal to the number of its vertices,  that is $\chi(K_n)=n$. My question is can we get a graph $G$ not containing $K_n$ but with $\chi(G)\geq n$, for $n\geq 3$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graphs $M_n$ formed by iterating the Mycielskian operation, where $M_1$ is the one-vertex graph. All these graphs are triangle-free, hence $K_n$-free for $n\ge3$, and $\chi(M_n)=n$. Thus for any fixed $n\ge3$, $M_n$ is a graph with the desired property: $K_n$-free but requiring at least $n$ colours. Furthermore, all graphs $M_k$ with $k>n$ also have the desired property.

Comment: according to the principle you mention above for $M_4$ we have 11 vertices so the $\chi(M_4)=4<11$. How we can interpret this?

Comment: @2468 Interpret what? The interpretation of $\chi(M_4)=4$ is that [the graph $M_4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) can be properly colored with $4$ colors, but not with fewer than $4$ colors.